# What is the generic term used for sensors that measure soil water tension?

Tags: hydrogeology, unsaturated-zone, environmental-sensors

Tensiometers are instruments used in measuring soil water matric potential (vadose zone water tension) by measuring the vacuum in a water-filled tube that contacts the soil through a porous cup:

[image: tensiometer]

*[Electronic tensiometer probe: (1) porous cup; (2) water-filled tube; (3) sensor-head; (4) pressure sensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensiometer_(soil_science))*

However there are other sensors that use electrical measurements to determine the matric potential, such as gypsum blocks and porous dielectric water potential sensors. If tensiometer refers to a specific instrument, what is the proper generic term for devices that measure matric potential?